# Javascript no jquery - Split a textareas single column list (unknown line count) & display in csv's of 150

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put together what I thought would be an easy solution for a friend.

He has a list of fan emails that he collects at gigs and off his website.

He sticks them in a single column file and saves them.

He needs to have them in comma delimited format containing 150 each, one single line.

He wants a "simple" local HTML form he can paste the list into and have the results displayed.

So, I started working on it but, it has proven past my ability.

So far I have some basics but, I really need help.
As you can see, I am really a beginner.

```
     <html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function makeit(){

        var enteredEmails = document.getElementById("emails").value;
        var cnt = document.getElementById("breakcnt").value;
        var mails = enteredEmails.toString();
        var textareacnt = '1';

        // Now I think I need to loop or create arrays of emails up to cnt //

        csvmails = mails.splice(0,cnt)

        // Then dynamically generate some textareas or boxes populated with a single comma delimited line of  cnt" emails //

 document.write("<textarea id=\"textareacnt\">" + csvmails + "</textarea>")

 textareacnt++; 

        }
        </script>
        </head><body>
        <form onsubmit="makeit();">
        <textarea name="emails" id="emails" rows="10" cols="75"></textarea><br />
        <input type="text" name="breakcnt" id="breakcnt"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    <textarea id="results"></textarea>
        </body></html>
```

The textarera will have emails pasted into it like:

```
amail1@sometld.com
bmail1@sometld.com
cmail1@sometld.com
amail4@sometld.com
zmail10@sometld.com
```

... up to 6000 fan emails he has collected over the years

He needs the results to be:

```
amail1@sometld.com,bmail1@sometld.com,cmail1@sometld.com,amail4@sometld.com,zmail10@sometld.com
```

up to 150 emails long as I am sure the last chunk or array will not contain 150.

I cant get anything to work and I spent 6 hours on this so far.

Can someone please help? I feel like a complete idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is split the text into an array and then splice the array in a loop and join the slices you take out like this:

```
var emails= document.getElementById('emails').value.split(/\s+/), list="";
while(emails.length) {
  list+=emails.splice(0,150).join(',')+"\n";
}
//list now has the result you are looking for
```

I have made an example of how to this here: http://jsfiddle.net/PfB42/2/

All you have to do is paste the emails into the text area and it will automatically change the format to the one you are looking for, and insert it to the `<pre>` area below the textarea

Comment: Wow thanks, that was fast and it did not time out with 8000 emails! Still I cannot find a way to put each of the lines into a textarea or field containing 150 emails per. This is needed so he can select the contents, copy and paste into his newsletter bcc field. Why am I having so much trouble? You guys did this FAST! It took me 6 hours to produce nothing..

Comment: @Jim_BO: i have updated my example to do it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/PfB42/1/

Comment: @Martin I editied the line in your code in attempt to do what I need: [code]document.getElementById('p').innerHTML='<input type=\"text\" value=\"'+list+'\">';[/code] and I got only one text field. I think this is very close to the solution. Thanks so much for your help but, I need a little more guidance.

Comment: Opps, just saw your comment. I am off to check it out.

Comment: HOLY CRAP, you are amazing! The only glitch I see is on the last textarea the comma is not removed after last email BUT, he will have to deal with it.  Thanks soooo Much!!! Now I will try to figure out how to put copy to clipboard buttons on each one. Man, again, you are amazing.

Comment: Now it removes trailing commas as well, have fun: http://jsfiddle.net/PfB42/2/ ;)

Comment: Thank you! I will not bother you anymore in case I have trouble with little add ons like the copy to clipboard buttons. You answered my question in full and perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: @Martin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433469/javascript-no-jquery-how-can-i-add-this-email-validator-function-to-this-exist asks you another question.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you want.
Don't be so hard on yourself mate :)

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function makeit(){

            var enteredEmails = document.getElementById("emails").value;
            var results = document.getElementById("results");


            var index = 0;
            var index2 = enteredEmails.indexOf("\n");
            while(true) {

                results.value += enteredEmails.substring(index, index2);

                index = index2+1;
                var index2 = enteredEmails.indexOf("\n", index+1);

                //EOF
                if(index2 == -1) {
                    results.value += ",";
                    results.value += enteredEmails.substring(index, enteredEmails.length);
                    break;
                } else {
                    results.value += ",";
                }

            }




        }
        </script>
</head><body>
    <form onsubmit="makeit();">
        <textarea name="emails" id="emails" rows="10" cols="75"></textarea><br />
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="makeit()">
    </form>
    <textarea id="results"></textarea>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, where does the split to 150 take place? I was in fact able to get the column to convert to csv with simply [code] document.write(emails.toString()) [/code] this morning but, it's the whole split and display that is killing me.

Comment: Oh. This script doesn't split the contents at all; it just replaces newlines ("\n") with commas, and spits it out in the results textArea. The example above makes use of the array split function, and its probably quicker than this.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, don't use that complicated scripts. Strings have functions exactly for that purpose:

```
var input = document.getElementById("emails").value;
input = input.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n"); // I hate this
var emails = input.split("\n"); // make an Array
var output = emails.join(","); // should we use ", " instead?
```

Of course you could put everyhing in one line ;-)