# Javascript no jquery - How do I add this function to existing javascript that is triggered by onload / onpaste?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

This is an add-on to my previously answered question.

[question 8423472](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423472/javascript-no-jquery-split-a-textareas-single-column-list-unknown-line-count)

I have tried to implement a validate function to this wonderful code to no avail.

Looks like I need more hand holding here.

This script is a slightly modified version of the quite excellent answer I received from @Martin Jespersen.

The script takes a single column list of emails and breaks it up into textareas containing single row comma delimited lists of no more than 150 addresses. Nice.

Below works great but, I need to add a basic validation function.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'>
function onpaste(e) {
var t = this;
var cnt='0';
setTimeout(function(){
var list = document.getElementById('t');
var emails= t.value.split(/\s+/), ta;
while(emails.length) {
cnt++;
ta = document.createElement('textarea');
ta.value = emails.splice(0,150).join(',').replace(/,\s*$/,'');
document.body.appendChild(ta);
}
document.getElementById('button1').value=cnt;
},1);
}
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('t').onpaste = onpaste;
}
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
<p><textarea id="t" rows="10" cols="50" class="textarea"></textarea><br /></p><br />
There are <input type="button" id="button1" value="0"> textareas
<pre id="p" class="pre"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

HOWEVER, the guy I made it for (actually @Martin made it) is not real meticulous about what he pastes into the textarea.

So, I am trying to implement a function that will reduce invalid emails / bad input.

I tried several ways including changing the onload event to a button in the page with onclick event.

I thought I was learning here but, I just can't wrap my brain around what I am doing wrong.

So, how can I insert this function, or just its' "validation" routine into one of the above functions?

```
function findEmailAddresses(StrObj) {
var separateEmailsBy = '\n';
var email = "<none>"; // if no match, use this
var emailsArray = StrObj.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); // yeah could be better 
if (emailsArray) {
email = "";
for (var i = 0; i < emailsArray.length; i++) {
if (i != 0) email += separateEmailsBy;
email += emailsArray[i];
      }
   }
return email;
}
```

Useage of findEmailAddresses function:

```
<textarea name=t rows=10 cols=50 onBlur="this.form.email.value=findEmailAddresses(this.value);"></textarea>
```

I tried calling the function individually in the functions above and even tried removing the function just inserting the code using "emails" instead of "this.value" in both cases. I even tried a two page approach. For some reason, I just can't implement this code into the working splitter. My results are either no effect or I break the thing.

Basically I tried many variations of inserting. Like below:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script language=javascript type='text/javascript'>
function onpaste(e) {
var t = this;
var cnt='0';
setTimeout(function(){
var list = document.getElementById('t');
var emails= t.value.split(/\s+/), ta;
//
findEmailAddresses(emails);
// also tried inserting code from function. ///
while(emails.length) {
cnt++;
ta = document.createElement('textarea');
ta.value = emails.splice(0,150).join(',').replace(/,\s*$/,'');
document.body.appendChild(ta);
}
document.getElementById('button1').value=cnt;
},1);
}
window.onload = function() {
// tried to trigger it here as well and even added a new split //
document.getElementById('t').onpaste = onpaste;
}
/////
 function findEmailAddresses(StrObj) {
    var separateEmailsBy = '\n';
    var email = "<none>"; // if no match, use this
    var emailsArray = StrObj.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); // yeah could be better 
    if (emailsArray) {
    email = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < emailsArray.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) email += separateEmailsBy;
    email += emailsArray[i];
          }
       }
    return email;
    }
////////
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
<p><textarea id="t" rows="10" cols="50" class="textarea"></textarea><br /></p><br />
There are <input type="button" id="button1" value="0"> textareas
<pre id="p" class="pre"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Much thanks to anyone who can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting return true; after your inline javascript.

Comment: That did nothing. There is no output on paste. Valid or not.

Comment: I also tried changing the findEmailAddresses(emails) to findEmailAddresses('emails') . Looks like I am just chasing my tail here. 5 days and still cannot figure this out. This old dog is seemingly not learning any new tricks.